# How do I download all these files in one go with wget?

Tags: linux, centos, wget

I want to download all these RPMs from SourceForge in one go with wget:
[Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hphp/files/CentOS%205%2064bit/SRPM/)

How do I do this?

Comment: The probably easiest way would be to follow the "direct mirror" link on one of these, and copy the URL. Then copy/paste all the filenames from the page you linked to into a text editor, and paste the server-directory part of the URL in front of each (a decent editor will do that on all lines in one go if you indent and Alt-select). Then remove all line breaks (replace \n with space) and copy/paste that onto the commandline. This is very convoluted, admittedly, but Sourceforge does not make it easy to mass-download with its redirection system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how for example HeaNet is one of the SF mirrors hosting this project (and many others), you could find out where SF redirects you, specifically:

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/h/project/hp/hphp/CentOS%205%2064bit/SRPM/

... and download that entire directory with the `-r` option (probably should use "no parent" switch, too).

Answer (score 1):

One of the two ways:

Create a script that parses the html file and gets the links that ends withs *.rpm, and download those links using wget $URL

Or start copy & pasting those urls and use:

wget $URL from the console.

Comment: Sorry, I have seen that it opens a page with a timeout, that would make it way harder to create a script, so it will be easier just downloading one by one...